# BitLocker Values

Tags: c#, wmi, bitlocker

I'm trying to get BitLocker information from a remote host. I used to do this using PowerShell (Get-BitLockerVolume) which would provide lots of useful information. When I try using C#, I don't get as much information back. Looking on [Microsoft's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secprov/win32-encryptablevolume) website and from [further research](https://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/security/microsoftvolumeencryption/win32_encryptablevolume/), I can't find anything to help me.

Does anyone know how to get the same output as Get-BitLockerVolume in C#?

By the way, this is what I've been testing within C#:

```
CimSession session = CimSession.Create(computerHostName);

IEnumerable<CimInstance> GI1 = session.QueryInstances(@"root\cimv2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption", "WQL", "SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume");

foreach(CimInstance i in GI1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MountPoint: {0}, Protection: {1}",
        i.CimInstanceProperties["DriveLetter"].Value,
        i.CimInstanceProperties["ProtectionStatus"].Value);
}
```

Comment: The user account you use matters, DriverLetter is a per-user setting.

Comment: PowerShell modules are typically implemented in either PowerShell or a .NET assembly (easily decompiled). `(Get-Command Get-BitLockerVolume).Module | Get-Module | Select Path` will point you directly to the source in this case. Looking at that (`Get-BitLockerVolumeInternal`), you'll see it uses the same CIM class as you're using, but calls a few more methods to get some data directly as properties. You can either replicate that stuff, or go the easy way and use a PowerShell pipeline in C# to just call `Get-BitLockerVolume` directly.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert ! Didn't know I could track back the source like that. I was hoping to only use C# but using PowerShell as well seems simpler in this case.

Comment: @JeroenMostert When I used a runspace and run PowerShell inside to the remote host, when running Get-Process I get the information back but I don't get anything back when using Get-BitLockerVolume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeroen recalls, you will be able to get that information calling methods on your WMI instances. As for the docs, `Win32_EncryptableVolume` only exposes the following properties:

```
class Win32_EncryptableVolume
{
  string DeviceID;
  string PersistentVolumeID;
  string DriveLetter;
  uint32 ProtectionStatus;
};
```

To easily get the information you need using WMI and method access, you can use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) library:

You can define for example your class like this:

```
public class Win32_EncryptableVolume : WMIInstance
{
  public string DeviceID {get; set;}
  public string PersistentVolumeID {get; set;}
  public string DriveLetter {get; set;}
  public int ProtectionStatus {get; set;}

  [WMIIgnore]
  public int Version {get; set;}

  public int GetVersion()
  {
     return WMIMethod.ExecuteMethod<int>(this)
  }
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
WmiHelper _helper = new WmiHelper("root\\Cimv2"); //Define the correct scope

List<Win32_EncryptableVolume> volumes = _helper.Query<Win32_EncryptableVolume>().ToList();

foreach(Win32_EncryptableVolume v in volumes)
{
    v.Version = v.GetVersion();
}
```

Comment: I suppose `public int Version => GetVersion()` would also do, if we don't care about caching the value or updating any instances? That would save on some initialization code.

Comment: So to get the same output as Get-BitLockerVolume I would have to query a couple of WMI locations and add them all together?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes!... yours would be much better implementation

Comment: @I.TDelinquent I imagine that you would have to do that